# Paying with a business credit card in Paypal

Tags: paypal

I have a business PayPal account and will be receiving payments from individuals and small businesses. At checkout, in the 'Pay with debit or credit card' section, there is only provision for a personal credit card. How do I make provision for a business MasterCard?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Paypal support issue.

Comment: It's a good question, and relates to web design as I'm a web designer and have this exact question for the website I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the wording on the PayPal payment page, there isn't a way to change this wording.  You are limited in what you can do with the layout.  However, depending on what type of account you have there are other options.  If you are using a Pro account, you can use API's and keep the merchant on your site so that you have more control over the checkout flow.  There are also hosted checkout pages that would work for what you are tyring to do as well.

Comment: Which hosted checkout option allows you to accept a Credit Card in the name of a company, not an individual?